# How sum String array numbers from a sqlite column in swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have a sqlite table on my `iOS` app and I want to sum all String numbers of a column of it. The column name is : "count"

I Wrote this code to get the numbers :

```
   let kiwi = DB.getInstance()
    let records = kiwi.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM zekrlist")
    for record in records {
        let structContact = StructContact()
        structContact.id = record.column["id"]?.asInt()
        structContact.count = record.column["count"]?.asString()
        print(structContact.count)
```

The print result is like this:

> 4
>
> 2

I want sum of these numbers as:

> 6

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let kiwi = DB.getInstance()
let count:Int = 0
let records = kiwi.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM zekrlist")
for record in records {
    let structContact = StructContact()
    structContact.id = record.column["id"]?.asInt()
    structContact.count = record.column["count"]?.asString()
    count = count + structContact.count.asInt()  // Int(structContact.count)
}
print(count)
```

Comment: it gives me this error: Value of type 'String' has no member 'asInt'

Comment: I changed the last line to :             count = count + Int(structContact.count)!   and its work Great ! thank You a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
let records = kiwi.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(columnName) AS resultName FROM tableName")
var sum = 0
for record in records
{
    sum += record.column["resultName"]?.asInt() ?? 0
}
```

Comment: you might want to add the swift code to retrieve the summed result as well.

Comment: what should I put instead of resultName ?

Comment: Put whatever you want and refer to the same thing in the loop below. Disclaimer:- I do not have the sqlite environment setup right now so please don't hate if this doesn't work